# company logo not visible in e-mail signature

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365

Our CEO doesn't want to use a transport rule to create outlook e-mail signatures because he wants to be able to edit his signature before sending an e-mail.

so we have to use a third-party tool to deploy e-mail signatures to clients. the logo we use in the signature is stored on our webserver which is in a DMZ network segment. The Server accepts http & https requests and can send https, everything else is protected by our firewall.

recipients of our e-mails don't see a logo, only if they click on "download images" they can see it. This doesn't occur when we send e-mails inside the company network.

Why does everyone else's signature seem to be visible without downloading it but our signature needs to be downloaded? Is there any security option i have to change to make this possible in Exchange, Firewall or Webserver?

I read somewhere that this is an expected behaviour, but then I can not understand why everyone elses logo is visible.

We use Exchange Online & Office365

Comment: Outlook is configured by default to block automatic picture downloads from the Internet. When you send an email to external recipients the logo needs to be downloaded from your DMZ web server, which is the internet from the perspective of the external recipient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downloading a picture from a link is a way for spammers or mailing list owners to track who has viewed a message, so Outlook does not download by default.

You are probably auto downloading it internally because the senders are in your address book, or you have added them to the trusted senders list, or the site is in your intranet zone, etc. For an external recipient this is not the case.

To work around this you can embed the image in the email rather than linking to it. 
http://www.mail-signatures.com/articles/images-in-email-signatures-linked-or-embedded/